# Tools for remote git commits?

Tags: git, commit

I have a webserver for development. All changes in source files which occur there are made through the ftp. After changes have been made I ought to connect through ssh and to make the commit from console. (It's not possible to have the local copy of the all source files and then just pull changes to remote server).
Question: Is there web oriented app for making commits on remote server, or maybe some GUI tool that can do it through the ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a simple shell function that ssh's to the remote machine and does a deploy. Tools like [fabric](https://github.com/bitprophet/fabric) make this easy for you.

You could also keep a bare repository on the remote machine with some hooks that do the deployment if you push to a specific branch. This would make things easier for you.